# Documentation for older version of Cherrypy

Tags: python, ajax, web, cherrypy

Hi I've written a small cherrypy http server in cherrypy version 3.2.0. But I have had a requirements change to deploy it on systems running version 2.3.0.

I use a couple of tools which have obviously been introduced in 3.x but cannot find documentation anywhere for 2.x??

1) Does anyone know where I can access 2.x documention?

or...

2) If anyone has experience with cherrypy could you suggest alternatives to the following code that will work with 2.x and 3.x...

`@cherrypy.tools.json_out()`

`cherrypy.quickstart(myViewer(), '/', config='my_viewer.conf')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are completely different beasts internally so there is no chance that you can easily backport from 3.x to 2.x.

Nonetheless this Wiki page will help you out understanding how to downgrade.

https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/wiki/Home

1) I don't think there is any CherryPy 2.x documentation available online.

2) Mostly tools in 3.x can be compared to filters in 2.x. However there was no Json filter in 2.x IIRC, so you will have to write your own I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

[2.3.0 source code tag](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/dca45ccb647914fcd2f8429ed780f17bf849528a/docs/book/?at=cherrypy-2.3.0)

Checkout the code base, and build the documentation

```
apt-get install mercurial
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy
cd cherrpy
hg pull && hg update cherrypy-2.3.0
cd docs/book
bash build.sh
firefox html/index.html
```